# How can I make a new CTP (CakePHP) file in NetBeans?

Tags: php, cakephp, netbeans

I have found a lot of info about adding CTP file support for NetBeans, but this is usually talking about code highlighting and treating a ctp file like a php file. This can be done at:

> Tools -> Options -> Miscellaneous -> Files

I have done this.

---

However, when I try to create a NEW ctp file. I do not have the option.

I tried going to `Tools -> Templates` to add a ctp template. There is no "new" button just an "add" button that looks for a file.

I created a file on my desktop called `cake_template.ctp` on my desktop. I added it to the PHP templates in the template manager. I called the template "PHP Cake Template".

Still when I go to create a new file, the option is not there. I restarted NetBeans, still the same.

I just want to create a new .ctp file, it shouldn't be this difficult. Does anyone know how?

I am using version 6.9.1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

just right click on the folder in the project view, and then say new php file. then just type the file_name.ctp in the field.

if you have .ctp it will not add .php

Answer (score 0):

You can add empty file by right click on the folder view, then click new empty file, after you can specify its extension.